# Why is (eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol "bitBlt")) -> #f

Tags: string, scheme, symbols, r5rs

R5RS 6.3.3 says

```
(eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol "bitBlt")) ==>  #f
```

Does this mean that

```
(eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol (symbol->string 'bitBlt))) ==> #f?
```

elk returns #t!

R5RS also says

```
(string->symbol "mISSISSIppi") ==> the symbol with name "mISSISSIppi"
```

(presumably this means 'mISSISSIppi)

and

```
(symbol->string 'Martin) ==> "martin"
```

meaning that symbol->string returns a string in standard case (lowercase in this example).

So if I expand my second example

```
(symbol->string 'bitBlt) ==> "bitblt"
(string->symbol (symbol->string 'bitBlt)) ==> 'bitblt
```

and therefore

```
(eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol (symbol->string 'bitBlt))) ==> #t
```

because symbols are case insensitive from R5RS

```
(eq? 'mISSISSIppi 'mississippi) ==> #t
```

So if I expand my original question

```
(string->symbol "bitBlt") ==> 'bitblt
```

and therefore

```
(eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol "bitBlt")) ==>  #t
```

Right? But R5Rs says #f!

Where am I going wrong here?

Why would this behaviour be specified?

Ref:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_8.html#SEC49

http://bugs.call-cc.org/browser/numbers/r4rstest.scm?rev=1 line 468

Actual session example:

```
3> (display 'bitBlt)
bitblt
3> (display (string->symbol "bitBlt"))
bitBlt
3> (eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol "bitBlt"))
#f
3> (eq? 'bitblt (string->symbol "bitBlt"))
#f
3> (eq? 'bitblt (string->symbol "bitblt"))
#t
3> (eq? 'bitBlt (string->symbol (symbol->string 'bitBlt)))
#t
3> (eq? 'mISSISSIppi 'mississippi)
#t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_446) you quote "assume[s] that the implementation's standard case is lower case". That means that the expression `'bitBlt` actually expands to the symbol `bitblt`. Symbols aren't actually case-insensitive; `read` may normalize case.

`string->symbol`'s semantics differ from that of `read` and the procedure may return a mixed-case symbol:

> This procedure can create symbols with names containing special characters or letters in the non-standard case, but it is usually a bad idea to create such symbols because in some implementations of Scheme they cannot be read as themselves.

In your implementation, `string->symbol` seems to normalize case as well. Check the output of

```
(display 'bitBlt)
(display (string->symbol "bitBlt"))
```

to be sure.

(My previous answer was wrong.)

Comment: I added session output to question. Thanks. I'm not certain it is a case issue. If it were a case issue, surely expression 3 or 4 should have been true? Since it is in R4RStest.scm I suspect something deeper, but I can't see what. Like (guessing) string->symbol must produce a unique symbol and not re-use storage of an existing symbol. It is not 'elk' that I care about - it could be wrong - I am trying to understand R5RS and, as well I suppose, this R4RStest.scm file. It seems to me that this sort of weirdness would stump dummies like me who may never work out what is going wrong.

Comment: @philcolbourn: it's pretty obvious, your `read` normalizes case while `string->symbol` doesn't. The result of `(string->symbol (symbol->string 'bitBlt))` should print as `bitblt` since the initial input is normalized to that.

Comment: That was my first thought, but Why then is (eq? 'bitblt (string->symbol "bitBlt")) ==> #f? (4th result from session output) and why does it care about symbol case when (eq? 'mISSISSIppi 'mississippi) ==> #t? (7th result)

Comment: @philcolbourn: in `(eq? 'bitblt (string->symbol "bitBlt"))`, the second symbol is not normalized because it comes from `string->symbol`. In `(eq? 'mISSISSIppi 'mississippi)`, both symbols are case-normalized because they come from `read` (implicitly).

Comment: Ok. I see! Your persistence is admirable. Thanks!